# Duplicate user created?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, merge-accounts

One of my questions got migrated here from SuperUser (which, by the way, I think was a mistake because I was asking about accesses to my Gmail account through IMAP, not about web applications).  It showed a user ["Paul Tomblin"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/599/paul-tomblin) but when I logged it with my OpenId, it created a new user ["Paul Tomblin"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/10854/paul-tomblin) instead of logging me into the 599 account.

When I first created my StackOverflow (and so probably ServerFault and SuperUser), I was using my LiveJournal account for my OpenId (because Gmail didn't work right).  After you guys got GMail OpenIds working, I associated my GMail OpenId with my StackOverflow account (and I thought my ServerFault and SuperUser accounts as well).  Is the 559 account associated with my LiveJournal OpenID, and can I get these two accounts merged?

Comment: Done. I also re-associated your 599 account with your other SE accounts. It has both OpenIDs associated with the account - you just have to set up which one you want as the primary.

Comment: On the migration - flag the Super User question for moderator attention. If they agree it was incorrectly migrated, they'll contact me or one of the other mods to coordinate the migration reversal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they can be merged - which one do you want to "keep"? Would you prefer to have the 599 ID or the 10854 ID account remain?

It might be easier to keep the 10854 account as that's the one that's properly associated with your other Stack Exchange accounts.

The 599 account is associated with your LiveJournal OpenID.

Comment: They're both pretty low rep and low usage, so I guess I'll keep the first one, the 559 one.  I'm going through all my other accounts to make sure I've associated GMail and LiveJournal with them so this doesn't happen again.

Comment: If it's easier to keep the 10854, then go ahead and keep that one.  I've only asked one question (which was asked elsewhere and migrated) and answered one (same question), so it's not like I'm going to be out of the reputation league running if I lose the wrong one. :-)

Comment: @Paul - too late - you've got the 599 one :)